# How to show popup according to which component redirect from in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

> The requirement is I want to show a modal popup with message user
> timeout when the user is redirected to the login page because of idle,
> but this popup shouldn't come up in the normal redirection. (if user
> goto sitename/login this modal shouldn't popup)
>
> what is the best way to do this?

```js
in app component
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
          this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
          this.timedOut = true;
          console.log(this.idleState);
           
          this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
 });
}
```

Comment: You could simply add a query param to the navigation like /login?reason=timeout

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MikeOne ,   but if we use query params , when user relaod it that page then model will comeup again right ?

Comment: Yes, unless you remove the param once you read it.